# Filtering Filtered DataView

Tags: dataview, asp.net-1.1

I have a DataSet which will be filtered twice like the following.
How can I set the RowFilter property of the DataView twice?
Or is there any other better implementation than the one below?

```
DataView dv = new DataView(myDataSet.Tables[0]);
dv.RowFilter = "approved = 1";
dv.Sort = "BookingDate";
foreach row{
    //Filter by shiftTime in filtered DataView
    foreach column{
        //Find date in filtered DataView
    }
}
```

Thank you in advance for your help.

Thanks,
artsylar

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you've already found the solution. I assume you have but I will still post a possible solution if it helps someone. It's in VB.NET though.

```
Dim dv_docs As New DataView(ds_allDocsInfo.Tables(0))
Dim rowFilter As String = ""
rowFilter = "DocumentStatus='Published' And templateFrameID='2'
dv_docs.RowFilter = rowFilter
DLDocument.DataSource = dv_docs
DLDocument.DataBind()
```

Note: To have multiple filters I have used 'And' and built a row filter separately before applying it to the DataView.

Hope this helps.